# How to get a value from one procedure to use in another one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create 2 procedures, one that inserts into the Sales table a sale made, and another that inserts into the Products_Sale table the products being sold based on the first procedure

How do I manage to get the PK created with the first procedure into the second one?

I tried using OUTPUT but something is wrong and when executing the procs it returns an error

So far what I've had wrote was

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_sell
(
    @idpay INT = NULL,
    @idclient INT = NULL,
    @idworker INT = NULL,
    @total SMALLMONEY = NULL,
    @date DATE = NULL,

    @idsell INT = NULL OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Sell
    (
        ID_Pay,
        ID_Client,
        ID_Worker,
        Total,
        Date
    )
VALUES
    (
        @idpay,
        @idclient,
        @idworker,
        @total,
        @date
    )

SELECT @idsell = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

and for the second proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_prod_sell
(
    @idsell INT = NULL,
    @id_forn_prod INT = NULL,

    @idprodsell INT = NULL OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

EXEC sp_sell @idsell = @idsell OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Sell
    (
        ID_sell,
        ID_Forn_Prod
    )
VALUES
    (
        @idsell,
        @id_forn_prod
    )
END
```

Comment: Where in this flow are things like `@total` expected to be supplied? You call `sp_sell` from inside `sp_prod_sell` but don't pass the values into that proc to be used in the call. Also don't use `sp_` prefix as that is a reserved prefix. Ideally don't use any such prefix

Comment: @total would be filled with the execution of the first proc, then I need to get the ID_Sell value generated by this first proc to the second one

Comment: The original call to `sp_sell` is supposed to read the output parameter then and then pass that in as a parameter to `sp_prod_sell` - and `sp_prod_sell` itself doesn't call `sp_sell`

Comment: but how exactly would I go about doing that? I'm having a bit of a trouble figuring out how to pass the parameter to another proc

Comment: How are you doing the original call to `sp_sell` that passes the values to insert? In TSQL or from an application?

Comment: from TSQL, directly with `exec sp_sell values`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `EXEC sp_sell @idsell = @idsell OUTPUT;` is not providing any other pameters so all the columns will be null. You need to either pass all the data through via the second procedure, or do as the below answer does.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `OUTPUT` to the parameter assignment when calling the stored procedure.  Something like

```
declare @idsell int
declare @idprodsell int

exec sp_sell @idpay = 1, @idclient = 23, @idworker = 44, @total= 23.3, @date = '20230123', @idsell = @idsell output
exec sp_prod_sell @idsell = @idsell, @id_forn_prod = 22, @idprodsell = @idprodsell output
```

Comment: When executing the second stored procedure it gives me an error because it's executing the first proc again to pass the value as OUTPUT, is there any way to just call the OUTPUT value?
Like, I only need to call the first proc to get the ID from the newly inserted row, I don't need to execute the entire first proc again.

Comment: You need to decide whether to pass @idsell in as an argument to sp_prod_sell or generate it inside sp_prod_sell by calling sp_sell as in my answer.  You would not do both.

Comment: how would I pass @idsell as an argument to the second procedure?

Comment: That's what the code in my answer does.